# program ignores everything after cin.get() and skips back to the menu

Tags: c++

I'm stuck with this problem and I've tried everything I can think of.  My program is a music database with a menu for selecting options.

I have a function for reading in data to add a new song to the database.  My cin.get() statements seem to work, and it's echoing back the right information.  But as soon as I get to the last cin.get(), it just skips straight back to the menu.  I put in some dummy cout statements after this chunk of code and they never execute.

Here the function I'm having trouble with. I can post the rest of the program if necessary. I would really appreciate help with this.  I'm betting this is something really simple, I'm just too much of a beginner to see what the problem is.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
void inputNew(songType songs[], int &numSongs)
{
    char songName[100];
    char artist[100];
    int min;
    int sec;
    char album[100];

    clearScreen();

    cout << "Enter the name of the song: ";
    cin.get(songName, 100, '\n');
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cout << "You entered: " << songName << endl;

    cout << "Enter the name of the artist: ";
    cin.get(artist, 100, '\n');
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cout << "You entered " << artist << endl;

    cout << "Enter the minutes: ";
    cin >> min;
    cout << "You entered " << min << "minutes" << endl;

    cout << "Enter the seconds: ";
    cin >> sec;
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cout << "You entered " << sec << "seconds" << endl;

    cout << "Enter the album name: ";
    cin.get(album, 100, '\n');
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');

    cout << "testing" << endl;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us. Lastly please learn how to use a debugger to step though your code, statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Is  «dummy cout» cout << testing? I cannot reproduce the issue. The execution reaches this statement for me.  But, pls, note, if one of cin fails to read data correctly (e.g. entered minutes cannot be converted to a number, or you just push enter), all consequent cin will be skipped. You need to check cin state after reading with cin.fail() or you may use cin.exceptions(ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit) with try/catch.

Comment: Is it correct to use it like this?  if (cin.fail())  cout << "failed" << endl; If so, it's giving me nothing.

Comment: You have clearScreen(). May it be called in another part of your program and hide from you your output?

Comment: I do have clearScreen() in a few places in the program.  I tried commenting them out, but I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

In the [repl](https://repl.it/@jemclain/project2) you posted in the comments `main` has a while loop.

```
while (answer != 'q')
{
    displayMenu(songs, answer, numSongs);
    processRequest(songs, answer, numSongs); // Internally calls inputNew
}
```

`displayMenu` clears the screen and writes the menu. If you don't break in some way the execution, you will not be able to see the text that `processRequest` wrote. You need to add an `std::cin.get()` after all your outputs (like at the end of `processRequest`). If you want you can add a message like `Press enter to continue...` right before `std::cin.get()`.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to berate someone for trying to post a potential solution. Discuss the approach, perhaps, but the current tone if not constructive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion lax9999.  It still doesn't work, though :(

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Lax9999: however, if you can’t yet comment and a question is unclear to you, focus on another question that *is* clear, until you have enough rep to post comments. This can stand as an answer (even if it is a wrong answer).

Comment: Posting answers that are correct and helpful is going to get you the requisite reputation points faster of course.

Comment: In my opinion what I wrote can be considered as an answer because pretty much every time I had problems with scanf or cin this solution worked fine.

Comment: @newGirl I tried to compile the code on windows using GCC and it works fine without any fixes. Which operating system and compiler are you using?

Comment: BTW, `std::cin.clear` only clears status bits, it does nothing to flush the input buffers.  Maybe you want `std::cin.ignore()`?

Comment: I'm using code::blocks on linux.  I just tried compiling and running with command line g++, and I also tried it on repl.it, but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: I've tried on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PettyWeeArtificialintelligence) too, but it works for me. I haven't included the function `clearScreen` though. Can you try to replicate the issue on repl.it and update your question with a link to it?

Comment: https://repl.it/@jemclain/project2 this is the link to the full program.  Just to clarify, the program compiles and runs just fine.  It's just the inputNew function that isn't doing what I want.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear why it doesn't work: in main you have a while loop that draws the menu and processes a request. In `processRequest` you have a switch that calls the function you want to execute. If the answer is 1, `inputNew` will be called. `inputNew` ends with some couts, so the function `inputNew` returns. `processRequest` returns too and the while loop will redraw the menu. In a nutshell add `std::cin.get();` after the couts in `inputNew` or after you call `inputNew` in `processRequest`.

Comment: You can try my solution [here](https://repl.it/repls/PettyWeeArtificialintelligence). If you want you can add a message like `Press enter to continue...`.

Comment: That did it!! I added a cin.get() after my function call in processRequest and that fixed the problem.  I tried putting cin.get() in a hundred different places, I just didn't think to try putting one there.  Thank you lax999, you just made life a lot less stressful for me.